# How do items go missing?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[image]

So in my current embark I havent found any Iron yet, and im guessing I wont find any. So I traded all of my gems for some Pig Iron bars (since I have Flux Stone) and Steel/Iron Armor. I had the items equipped to my military after trading and not long after noticed that the items were missing along with everything I traded.

**What is happening and how do I prevent it from happening in the future?** This seems to happen everytime I trade and havent really had solid proof till now.

Comment: sorry, bad cropping job on my part, if you zoom in on the page you can see it better. The picture just shows how it says missing item

Comment: Never had anything like that happen to me. Probably a new bug.

Comment: Are you using any mods, and have any dwarves died?

Comment: @RavenDreamer im using lazynewbpack and 2 dwarves died but before this happened

Comment: @Paralytic I meant other than graphics mods. Phoebus (from lazynewbpack) shouldn't affect things. I'm not sure; I've never seen something like this.

Comment: @RavenDreamer nope nothing else

Comment: Any miltary fallen into magma? I'm also unsure if items can get washed off map.

Comment: i figured it out actually, what happened was i has hitting "o" while trading i guess that's to give an offering. not sure how you actually trade stuff then, along with that i would equip the items i thought were mine so obviously when the caravan left the item was no longer in the stock option @RavenDreamer

Comment: if someone else wants to type out the answer go for it.

Comment: @Paralytic there's nothing wrong with a self-answer. Trading is simply "T", or "t" I believe. Perhaps a second question, "How do I trade with merchants?" is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was that I had been offering my items away as gifts and not actually trading. So naturally before the merchants left i would attempt to equipped the steel armor I purchased and when the merchants left the item would be "missing".